# Why do I have to reference the user model this way

Tags: django

I was working on a Django project and I was trying to do something like this to make sure that my model worked no matter what user model is set.

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, )
    description = models.TextField()
    seller = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model())
```

However when I did this it resulted in errors telling me the user model couldn't be accessed so I had to change it to this

```
from django.conf import settings

class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, )
    description = models.TextField()
    seller = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

This works fine but I thought I have done this in the past using the first method. The only difference that time being that I was using a custom user model. They both seem like they are doing the same thing to me so why do I have to use the second method? And does get_user_model() not work with the default user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the source code of the get_user_model() in django:

```
def get_user_model():
    """
    Returns the User model that is active in this project.
    """
    from django.db.models import get_model

    try:
        app_label, model_name = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.split('.')
    except ValueError:
        raise ImproperlyConfigured("AUTH_USER_MODEL must be of the form 'app_label.model_name'")
    user_model = get_model(app_label, model_name)
    if user_model is None:
        raise ImproperlyConfigured("AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model '%s' that has not been installed" % settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    return user_model
```

As you can see, it pulls the AUTH_USER_MODEL variable from your settings as you do but extracting the app_label and the user class itself. If it does not work you should see one of the two errors in the terminal when this call is done.

Answer (score 1):

I think your answer lies in the [Django source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py#L133).  It depends on your setup what happens.  [Older versions](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.6.x/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py#L117) might do it a bit differently.